# react-native:　prevent the user from touching any component？

Tags: react-native

react-native: add a cover view at the top layer of the current screen to prevent the user from touching any component.

When the user touches one component, I need to judge is the user login or not. If the user doesn't log in. I need to alert 'Please register first', and navigate to the `Register` screen. My issue is how to prevent the user from touching any component.Due to the user can touch the same component again, then the simulator will navigate the `Register` screen more than one time.
I am using the `react-native-easy-toast` to show the hint window. 
How to add a cover view at the top of the current screen? I add a view and set the style `index` '999', but it doesn't work.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#EBF0F2',
    },
    coverV: {
        backgroundColor:'red',
        width:width,
        height:height,
        zIndex:9999,
    },
    title: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        flex: 1,
        height: 42,
        width: width,
        opacity: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'transparent'
    },
    icons: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
});





   return(
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" barStyle="light-content" translucent={true}/>
          <Banner resources={tempArray} itemTouchFun={this.bannerNavigateFunc}/>
            <View style={styles.title}>
                <Image source={require('../../img/tfind.png')}/>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.icons}>
              <Icon source={require('../../img/doctspec.png')}
                   onPress={this.onDoctor.bind(this)}
                title='Icon1' />
              <Icon source={require('../../img/osmedical.png')}
                onPress={this.onOSMed}
                title='Icon2' />
              <Icon source={require('../../img/newdrugs.png')}
                onPress={this.onMedicineBook}
                title='Icon3' />
              <Icon source={require('../../img/reservation.png')}
                onPress={this.onOSMed}
                title='Icon4' />
            </View>

            {this.renderNewsTabs()}
            {this.renderNews()}
            <View style={styles.coverV} />
            <Toast ref="toast" position='center' positionValue={200}
                   fadeInDuration={750} fadeOutDuration={1000} opacity={0.8} />
        </ScrollView>
    );}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to prevent user to use any functionality until user is loggedin. So if a user clicks any where in the screen a alert will appear which notify the user to register or login. So the conclusion i came up with is:

Encapsulate the whole view with a TouchableWithoutFeedback, so whenever the onPress event fires in the view then a alert will appear, the code is as follows.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#EBF0F2',
    },
    coverV: {
        backgroundColor:'red',
        width:width,
        height:height,
        zIndex:9999,
    },
    title: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        flex: 1,
        height: 42,
        width: width,
        opacity: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'transparent'
    },
    icons: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
});


export default class TouchView extends Component { 

  contructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    disable: true //prevents from pressing on buttons
    showAlert: false
   }
  }

  componentDidMount() 
  {
    if(user is logged in)
    {
      this.setState({ disable: false })
    }
  } 

   touchAnywhere()
   {
     this.setState({ showAlert: !this.state.showAlert })//showAlert 
     //navigate to login or register
   } 
   render()
  {
   return(
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = { () => this.touchAnywhere()} 
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)" barStyle="light-content" translucent={true}/>
          <Banner resources={tempArray} itemTouchFun={this.bannerNavigateFunc}/>
            <View style={styles.title}>
                <Image source={require('../../img/tfind.png')}/>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.icons}>
              <Icon disable source={require('../../img/doctspec.png')}
                   onPress={this.onDoctor.bind(this)}
                title='Icon1' />
              <Icon disable source={require('../../img/osmedical.png')}
                onPress={this.onOSMed}
                title='Icon2' />
              <Icon disable source={require('../../img/newdrugs.png')}
                onPress={this.onMedicineBook}
                title='Icon3' />
              <Icon disable source={require('../../img/reservation.png')}
                onPress={this.onOSMed}
                title='Icon4' />
            </View>

            {this.renderNewsTabs()}
            {this.renderNews()}
            <View style={styles.coverV} />
            {this.state.showAlert?  
            <Toast ref="toast" position='center' positionValue={200}
                   fadeInDuration={750} fadeOutDuration={1000} opacity={0.8} /> 
             : null}
        </ScrollView>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );} 
}
```

Cheers :)